# Why does my TeamSpeak3 server say "administrator privileges have not yet been claimed"?

Tags: teamspeak

I connect to my TeamSpeak3 server, which I have set up on [gameservers.com](http://www.gameservers.com).

The first time I entered the privilege key that I got from the website and logged on with my user. It has these two icons when connected:

1. (C) Channel Admin (Channel Group)
2. (S) Server Admin (Server Group)

I can manage the server just fine.

Yet, every time I connect to the server I get this dialog:

[image: Enter privilege key]

If I ask the gameservers.com config website to reset my privilege key and then use that I get this error message:

[image: Failed to use privilege key: duplicate entry]

So what have I done wrong, and how do I fix this?

The client is 64-bit and running on Windows 10, and is version 3.0.19.4, freshly updated.

The connection log:

```
<22:06:59> Trying to resolve hostname xxx.yyy.zzz
<22:07:00> Trying to connect to server on xxx.yyy.zzz:pppp
<22:07:00> Welcome to TeamSpeak, check www.teamspeak.com for latest infos.
<22:07:00> Connected to Server: "xxx.yyy.zzz"
```

so no useful information there either.

Comment: You should contact your service provider for support.

Comment: Did you try removing the old key? I had a similar problem and I removed the key then re-added the new one. I think it is in `Permissions`. This was a while back however.